# Custom status code when jwt validation fails

Tags: jwt, envoyproxy

I was wondering if there is a way to specify a custom status code to be returned when the jwt validation fails in `envoy.filters.http.jwt_authn`. Normally this returns a 401 status code but I would like to change it to a custom status code like 443.

I would like to do this because I need a way to somehow, in my client, differentiate between the 401 that envoy could return and the 401 that the server behind envoy may return. I hope I made myself clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Local reply modification](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_conn_man/local_reply) can modify the response by Envoy itself.
Please try the configuration if it can meet your requirement.